# c: const in the dimension of arrays reports errors

Tags: c, arrays, constants, dimensions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int N = 5;

int main()
{
    int vett[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem in this part of code? the compiler report me these error and warnings:

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
warning: (near initialization for 'vett') [enabled by default]
```

I know I can use the define directive to solve but I used to program in c++ and I don't want to change my old habits using `const`. There is something I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C++, even with `const int N = 5`, `N` is not considered as a constant expression in C. So `int vett[N]` is not a normal (fixed length) array, it's a variable length array.

In this case, you should still use:

```
#define N 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using variable length arrays. Variable length arrays do not have an initializer. You need to initialize it using a loop. Note that, in C

```
const int N = 5;
```

doesn't mean `N` is constant (unlike in C++). Therefore `int vett[N]` declares `vett` as a variable length array.

Comment: I don't think he meant to use a variable-length array.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `int vett[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` and the compiler will automatically determine how big your array is because you already determined the values to it.

Comment: And then you can use `const int N = (sizeof(vett)/sizeof(*vett));` if you want to know the size...